# How to create files based on dynamic data

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a query on MS Access 07 that looks like the example below. The data is dynamic, so the number of zones will change each week.

```
     ZONE     ERROR

    ZONE 1 | ERROR 1
    ZONE 1 | ERROR 3
    ZONE 2 | ERROR 4
    ZONE 2 | ERROR 5
    ZONE 3 | ERROR 1
    ZONE 3 | ERROR 3
```

Each week, I need to run this procedure to create a separate Excel file for each zone that is present that week. At the moment, I'm thinking that I might need to import the data into Excel and then used the advanced filter to ID each zone into a new column, Unique Zones, and then run a VBA code that will create a new file based on the data in the Unique Zones column...not sure if I am on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already talking about using VBA code in Excel you might not be averse to a VBA solution in Access.

Let's say that your table (or query) is called [ZoneErrors]. You could create something like the following VBA function in Access and then invoke it from an Access macro:

```
Public Function ExportZoneErrors()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, _
        excelFileName As String

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [ZONE] FROM [ZoneErrors]", dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    On Error Resume Next
    cdb.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpErrorsForJustOneZone"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("tmpErrorsForJustOneZone", _
            "SELECT * FROM [ZoneErrors] WHERE [ZONE]='" & rst!ZONE & "'")
    qdf.Close
    cdb.QueryDefs.Refresh

    ' build Excel file name (probably needs to be fancier in production)
    excelFileName = "Errors for " & rst!ZONE & ".xlsx"  ' e.g., "Errors for ZONE 1.xlsx"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tmpErrorsForJustOneZone", excelFileName

    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Function
```